# Push notifications not working - Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've checked my code and im not sure if im missing anything when I send a message threw firebase it sends but on my simulator it doesn't show the notification.Im using apnsKey I really have no idea what's going wrong is there anyway to trouble shoot or find outlive been stuck on this for a little while now

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Stripe
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging


 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder ,UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    initializeStripe()


    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    //=============================
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    //==========================


    return true
}







//MARK:STRIPE
//=====================================================================
func initializeStripe(){
    STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = Constants.publishableKey

    stripeClient.sharedClient.baseUrlString = Constants.baseUrlString

}








func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

  // Print message ID.
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }

  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

  // Print message ID.
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }

  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)

  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}





  }
   @available(iOS 10, *)
  extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                          willPresent notification: UNNotification,
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

// With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
// Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)

// Change this to your preferred presentation option
completionHandler([])
  }

   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                          didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                          withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)

completionHandler()
}
}


 extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("token fcm: \(fcmToken) boom")

    let dataDict: [String : String] = ["token" : fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil,  userInfo: dataDict)

  }

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("messae data  :\(remoteMessage.appData)")
}


   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Xcode stable release 11.3.*, to test push notification on iOS you need a real device. It is not possible to test on simulator. However, you can download Xcode 11.4 beta if you do not have a real device handy.

You can find the following in the official [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes) of Xcode 11.4 under the section Simulator -> New Features

> Simulator supports simulating remote push notifications, including
>   background content fetch notifications. In Simulator, drag and drop an
>   APNs file onto the target simulator. The file must be a JSON file with
>   a valid Apple Push Notification Service payload, including the “aps”
>   key. It must also contain a top-level “Simulator Target Bundle” with a
>   string value that matches the target application‘s bundle identifier.

Comment: AHH thank you for letting me know I do have an iPhone but I  mistakenly updated it to iOS 13.4 and now Xcode won't allow me to connect it because its too ahead of it. it suggests upgrading Xcode but I have the most recent version of Xcode meaning apple hasn't released the version that allows iOS 13.4